# Como olvidar un estilo de bootstrap con css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Ando creando una pagina web con html+css+js+boostrap+jquery para ver el codigo: view-source:https://jpb-global.com/

y me pasa lo siguiente:

Cuando abro el sitio en firefox se ve excelente:

[image: Firefox movil]

Pero cuando yo abro el sitio en google chrome movil se ve feo

```
<!--Products-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="card border-0 product productA">
                                <p class="text-center">XPRINTER</p>
                                <img src="products/productA/img.jpg" alt="">
                                <p class="text-center">$300</p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="card border-0 product productB">
                                <p class="text-center">Cinta mediana 10x50cm</p>
                                <img src="products/productB/img.jpg" alt="">
                                <p class="text-center">$500</p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="card border-0 product productC">
                                <p class="text-center">Cinta dorada 8x300</p>
                                <img src="products/productC/img.jpg" alt="">
                                <p class="text-center">$100</p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="card border-0 product productD">
                                <p class="text-center">Impresora bluetooth</p>
                                <img src="products/productD/img.jpg" alt="">
                                <p class="text-center">$900</p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="card border-0 product productE">
                                <p class="text-center">Filtros 6003</p>
                                <img src="products/productE/img.jpg" alt="">
                                <p class="text-center">$1100</p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: tengo un media query que a los 700px me lanza un evento, pero yo quiero saber como cambiar esos col-5 a col-12 para que cada producto se muestre uno a uno por fila????

Comment: Cambiar los col ?? Solo necesitas un display diferente, por favor muestra todo tu codigo, incluyendo el css

Comment: Bootstrap está pensado para ser responsivo desde el principio. Si quieres cambiar de forma adaptativa el comportamiento de un elemento basado en el tamaño del `viewport` debe usar las clases de Bootstrap creadas para ese propósito. Un contenedor que se adapte a diferentes tamaños podría tener las siguientes clases (todas a la vez): `col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6`. Así el elemento se adaptará a ocupar el espacio adecuado (de acuerdo a la grilla de Bootstrap y el tamaño del contenedor padre) según el ancho del `viewport`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Eres un genio... esa era la respuesta, gracias :)